# How to run a command, which executes another terminal running a script, in the backgroud

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I'm currently writing a BASH script that scans certain text files. There are thousands of text files so I wrote another script that divides up how many articles there are and distributes the load into other terminals which will then run the scanning script. My problem is that when I run my load distribution script I don't want 10 different terminals popping on my screen. Somehow I have to put these terminals in the background yet still run. I know there is a command `&` that supposedly allows you to do this, but the terminals still pop on my screen.

So far I have this command:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
gnome-terminal -x ./script $a $b $c $d
done
```

Five terminals running `./script` pop out on the screen. I want them to just run in the background and so they don't pop on the screen. Simply adding `&` to the end of the `gnome-terminal` command doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Generically speaking, screen or tmux could be options for your case. They are "headless" terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to epx (first person to comment the question) there is actually a very simple way to run 10 different terminals in the background:

`screen -d -m ./script`

if u run this in a for loop you can create multiple terminals in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use parenthesis to create a subshell:

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
    (./script $a $b $c $d)&
done
```

Comment: if I run it the way this is written the terminals still pop up. If I run it like this: `(gnome-terminal -x ./script $a $b $c $d)&` nothing happens again

Comment: Odd... Does your ./script call gnome-terminal inside of itself? Otherwise, I don't know why that would open any new terminals, all it does is run the script in a subshell.